# How to add a custom decorator to a FastAPI route?

Tags: python, python-decorators, fastapi, pydantic

I want to add an `auth_required` decorator to my endpoints.
(*Please consider that this question is about decorators, not middleware*)

So a simple decorator looks like this:

```
def auth_required(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if user_ctx.get() is None:
            raise HTTPException(...)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

So there are 2 usages:

```
@auth_required
@router.post(...)
```

or

```
@router.post(...)
@auth_required
```

The first way doesn't work because `router.post` creates a router that saved into `self.routes` of APIRouter object. The second way doesn't work because it fails to verify pydantic object. For any request model, it says `missing args, missing kwargs`.

So my question is - how can I add any decorators to FastAPI endpoints? Should I get into `router.routes` and modify the existing endpoint? Or use some `functools.wraps` like functions?

Comment: Is there a reason you need it to be a decorator? Coming from Flask to FastAPI, I sometimes think I need a decorator, but a [custom APIRoute class](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-request-and-route/) for endpoints that need auth or a Depends(User) injection can also solve the problem.

Comment: I want to add that decorator to some endpoints, not every. So custom APIRoute class (Im actually using it) doesnt help. And I have an issue with middleware - it works in another thread, so I can't set up global context variable from another thread. I saw some solutions to it, but now i really want to know is decorators possible.

Comment: The recommended style with FastAPI seems to be to use Dependencies. You add something like `user: User = Depends(auth_function)` to the path or function. That gets called before your endpoint function, similar to how a decorator wraps it. It should also have access to the req-resp context.

Comment: I know how to use depends. It has access to context, but since it is working in another thread, im getting empty context in main thread.

Comment: "Depends" also can't do any "around" actions (it can't do stuff after the route method body has completed.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

> How can I add any decorators to FastAPI endpoints?

As you said, you need to use [**`@functools.wraps(...)`**--(PyDoc)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) decorator as,

```
from functools import wraps

from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel


class SampleModel(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int


app = FastAPI()


def auth_required(func):
    @wraps(func)
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return await func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


@app.post("/")
@auth_required # Custom decorator
async def root(payload: SampleModel):
    return {"message": "Hello World", "payload": payload}
```

The main caveat of this method is that you can't access the `request` object in the wrapper and I assume it is your primary intention.

If you need to access the request, you must add the argument to the router function as,

```
from fastapi import Request


@app.post("/")
@auth_required  # Custom decorator
async def root(request: Request, payload: SampleModel):
    return {"message": "Hello World", "payload": payload}
```

---

I am not sure what's wrong with the FastAPI middleware, after all, the ***`@app.middleware(...)`*** is also a decorator.

Comment: can you please elaborate on the `@app.middleware(...)` you mean that can work as decorators also? any example or tutorial of this?

Comment: This works for post requests but not for get requests. Any idea why?

Comment: `@auth_required` is independent of the request method.

Comment: @AnkitJain Please make sure to declare the endpoint functions with `async def`. Above `@auth_required` decorator will only work with functions declared with `async def`. If you don't use `async`/`await` in endpoint functions, just drop it from `def wrapper(*args, **kwargs)` definition.

Comment: @FahadMunir Thanks a lot! This worked. I have added async in endpoint functions. However, this was not an issue with post requests.

Comment: @FahadMunir Hi, I want to ask question, why I got error when I remove `async` of `wrapper`? But after adding `async` everything will work.  How it work?

Comment: "what's wrong with the FastAPI middleware"

Two things about Middlewares: they apply to all routes so you end up having to write a bunch of awkward centralized conditionals. Also, they don't have access to the deserialized object(s) passed to the controller method. All they have is the raw request.

Answer (score 16):

Simply use the [dependencies](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/dependencies-in-path-operation-decorators/#add-dependencies-to-the-path-operation-decorator) inside of the path operation decorator:

```py
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, Header, HTTPException

app = FastAPI()


async def verify_token(x_token: str = Header()):
    if x_token != "fake-super-secret-token":
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="X-Token header invalid")


async def verify_key(x_key: str = Header()):
    if x_key != "fake-super-secret-key":
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="X-Key header invalid")
    return x_key


@app.get("/items/", dependencies=[Depends(verify_token), Depends(verify_key)])
async def read_items():
    return [{"item": "Foo"}, {"item": "Bar"}]
```

Comment: This is not a custom decorator though.

Answer (score 9):

Here is how you can use a decorator that adds extra parameters to the route handler:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from pydantic import BaseModel


class SampleModel(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int


app = FastAPI()

def do_something_with_request_object(request: Request):
    print(request)

def auth_required(handler):
    async def wrapper(request: Request, *args, **kwargs):
        do_something_with_request_object(request)
        return await handler(*args, **kwargs)

    # Fix signature of wrapper
    import inspect
    wrapper.__signature__ = inspect.Signature(
        parameters = [
            # Use all parameters from handler
            *inspect.signature(handler).parameters.values(),

            # Skip *args and **kwargs from wrapper parameters:
            *filter(
                lambda p: p.kind not in (inspect.Parameter.VAR_POSITIONAL, inspect.Parameter.VAR_KEYWORD),
                inspect.signature(wrapper).parameters.values()
            )
        ],
        return_annotation = inspect.signature(handler).return_annotation,
    )

    return wrapper


@app.post("/")
@auth_required # Custom decorator
async def root(payload: SampleModel):
    return {"message": f"Hello {payload.name}, {payload.age} years old!"}
```

Comment: Tried, but got `TypeError: wrapper() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'`

Comment: @JPG. I have updated the code after a lot of investigation and testing. However, I have tested with my own code; I haven't tested the code above.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/md2perpe/ee146e547a0bd910ea9683a2eea47c59

Comment: same error `TypeError: wrapper() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'`

Comment: @gocreating. Did you try my gist?

Comment: @md2perpe Sure, but my handler takes both positional and keyword args: `def create_user(user: schemas.UserCreate, session: Session = Depends(get_session)):`
so I get `ValueError: non-default argument follows default argument`

Comment: I have answered myself on fastapi's issue:
https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2662

Comment: @md2perpe: error regarding positional arguments occurs when decorator is applied to function with default values. Some additional logic are needed to provide list of parameters in order of positional parameter `(a, b)`, parameters with default `(c=1, d=2)`, keyword-only parameter i.e `(*args)`, etc...

Answer (score 2):

In addtion to JPG's answer, you can access the `Request` object inside your decorator with `kwargs.get('request')`. A full decorator would look something like:

```
def render_template(template):
    """decorator to render a template with a context"""
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

            # access request object
            request = kwargs.get('request')

            context = func(*args, **kwargs)
            if context is None:
                context = {}
            return templates.TemplateResponse(template, {**context, 'request': request})
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

The decorated function will need to take the `Request` as a parameter, however.

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution can depending on the situation lead to problems. In my case, the decorator was not an "auth_required" but a "use_cached" answer one and I was using a `nonlocal` var. As a result I was getting:

```
RuntimeError: cannot reuse already awaited coroutine
```

This is happening because as the code is proposed, it uses async / await in two locations / functions. If you get this error, to avoid it, you need to get rid of the extra async / await.

This has the disadvantage of breaking the aesthetics and that adding your decorator slightly changes the following function (you drop `async`). It has the advantage that the code produces no errors and is correct however...

**TL;DR:**

```
def auth_required(func):
    @wraps(func)
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs) #DO NOT WAIT
    return wrapper

@app.post("/")
@auth_required # Custom decorator
def root(payload: SampleModel): #NOT ASYNC
    return {"message": "Hello World", "payload": payload}
```