# How to specify dependencies for the entire router?

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

```py
class User(BaseModel):
    name: str
    token: str

fake_db = [
    User(name='foo', token='a1'),
    User(name='bar', token='a2')
]

async def get_user_by_token(token: str = Header()):
    for user in fake_db:
        if user.token == token:
            return user
        else:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail='Invalid token')


@router.get(path='/test_a', summary='Test route A')
async def test_route_a(user: User = Depends(get_user_by_token)):
    return {'name': user.name}


@router.get(path='/test_b', summary='Test route B')
async def test_route_a(user: User = Depends(get_user_by_token)):
    return {'name': user.name}
```

I would like to avoid code duplication. Is it possible to somehow set the line `user: User = Depends(get_user_by_token)` for the entire router? At the same time, I need the `user` object to be available in each method.

It is very important that the openapi says that you need to specify a header with a token for the method.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a custom decorator to a FastAPI route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64497615/how-to-add-a-custom-decorator-to-a-fastapi-route)

Comment: @WederRibas no because it just does token verification but i need to get the user object in the method

Comment: TMK, if you want the return value of the dependency, you have to specify it on each individual endpoint method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `dependencies` parameter to add [global dependencies](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/global-dependencies/) when creating the `router` instance:

```py
router = APIRouter(dependencies=[Depends(get_user_by_token)])
```

or, when adding the `router` to the `app` instance:

```py
app.include_router(router, dependencies=[Depends(get_user_by_token)])
```

Please have a look at FastAPI's documentation on [Dependencies](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/#dependencies) for more details.

As for getting the return value of a global dependency, you can't really do that. The way around this issue is to store the returned value to [`request.state`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#about-requeststate) (as described [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/4246#issuecomment-986245350)), which is used to store arbitrary state (see the implementation of [`State`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/212fa46b23be0701a5963cdeff14f05ed352e22a/starlette/datastructures.py#L674) as well). Hence, you could have something like this:

```py
def get_user_by_token(request: Request, token: str = Header()):
    for user in fake_db:
        if user.token == token:
            request.state.user = user
    # ...
```

Then, inside your endpoint, you could retrieve the user object using `request.state.user`, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74011067/17865804).

Comment: i know i can do that, but how can i get the data that the ```get_user_by_token``` function returns?

Comment: @kshnkvn You add it to the function where you need it as well. The result from the dependency will be cached, so it isn't reevaluated. Or you can use `request.state` as Christ has edited to show; but generally I prefer using the dependency in both locations, as it makes it more expressive about which values are available to the controller function.